# JSP: Problems Interpreting a Variable

Tags: jsp, liferay, scriptlet

This is my first post and I'm having problems with a servlet to interpret a variable I created to sequentially name two TAGs on a page running with Liferay.

Apparently the JSP interprets correctly for some TAGs and some does not. This is strange to me.

The following is an example of the code:

- I created the "sequencia" variable to create an order

> ```
> <div id="buttons<%=sequencia%>">
>    <aui:a href="javascript:printdiv('content<%=sequencia%>');" cssClass="bt_esquerda<%=sequencia%>">Imprimir<%=sequencia%></aui:a>
> ```

- The result that returns in the code is this

> ```
> <div id="buttons1">
>    <a href="javascript:printdiv(&#039;content&lt;%=sequencia%&gt;&#039;);"
> ```
>
> class="bt_esquerda<%=sequencia%>">Imprimir1

Does anyone have any idea WHY it can not resolve within the single and double quotation marks of the `<a>` tag, but can `<div>`?

Even if you do not know, do you have any alternative ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of issue is aui:a represents custom aui anchor tag; which has its implementation whereas div is generic html tag.

You may use any of below alternative
`<aui:a href="javascript:;"  onClick='<%="javascript:printdiv(\'content+<%=sequencia%>+\');" cssClass="bt_esquerda<%=sequencia%>">Imprimir<%=sequencia%></aui:a>`

`<aui:a href='<%="javascript:printdiv(\'content+<%=sequencia%>+\');" cssClass="bt_esquerda<%=sequencia%>">Imprimir<%=sequencia%></aui:a>`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem creating a string before the  TAG and using it instead that way.

> ```
> String link = "javascript:printdiv(\'content" + sequencia + "\');";
>
> <aui:a href="<%=link%>" ...
> ```

Thanks for your help, Pankajkumar.

Comment: If Pankajkumar's answer solved your issue, you should consider accepting his answer! [See why/how here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/156615)